# How to connect LINKSYS wifi repeater to an open wifi with Login portal

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have LINKSYS EA6900 V2 router. I am trying to use it as a wireless repeater for a open wifi.
The problem is that the open wifi has a user base authentication and login page open imminently when i connect to that wifi. So When i config my repeater to that network it connected but not showing that login page and thats why it has no internet connectivity. How can i get the login page through router?

Comment: EA6900 v2 is a MediaTek, not currently supported by DD-WRT

Comment: https://community.linksys.com/t5/Access-Points/Linksys-EA6900-Router-has-Captive-Portal-capability/td-p/1216852